# Class eval passing the class varibale by reference

Tags: ruby, class-eval

***The following code snippet:***

```
class A
end
    @class = eval("A")
    @class.class_eval do
        @@attr = 100
        def self.get_attr
            @@attr
        end
        def self.set_attr(_x)
            @@attr = _x
        end
    end

    class B
    end

    @class = eval("B")
    @class.class_eval do
        @@attr = 100
        def self.get_attr
            @@attr
        end
        def self.set_attr(_x)
            @@attr = _x
        end
    end
    a = A.new
    b = B.new
    A.set_attr(103)
    B.set_attr(222)
    puts A.get_attr
    puts B.get_attr
```

Class variable is getting shared.

***Result:***

222
222

Comment: So, what's the question?

Comment: Why is the class variable getting shared?

Comment: I expected some result as 103 and 222 instead of 222 and 222

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you set not the variable you think you do.

```
class A; end

@class = eval("A")
@class.class_eval do
  class_variable_set :@@attr, 100

  def self.get_attr
    class_variable_get :@@attr
  end

  def self.set_attr(_x)
    class_variable_set :@@attr, _x
  end
end

class B
end

@class = eval("B")
@class.class_eval do
  class_variable_set :@@attr, 100

  def self.get_attr
    class_variable_get :@@attr
  end
  def self.set_attr(_x)
    class_variable_set :@@attr, _x
  end
end

A.set_attr(103)
B.set_attr(222)
puts A.get_attr
puts B.get_attr

# >> 103
# >> 222
```

When I run your code, it gives several warnings of "Access to class variable from toplevel". So, apparently, you're setting and reading class variables of `main` object, not of your classes.

Answer (score 0):

see the below code:

```
class A
end
@class = eval("A")
@class.class_eval do
    @@attr = 100
    def self.get_attr
        @@attr
    end
    def self.set_attr(_x)
        p "hi"
        @@attr = _x
    end
end

class B
end

@class = eval("B")
@class.class_eval do
    @@attr = 100
    def self.get_attr
        @@attr
    end
    def self.set_attr(_x)
        p "hi"
        @@attr = _x
    end
end
a = A.new
b = B.new
A.set_attr(103)
B.set_attr(222)

p A.class_variable_defined?(:@@attr) 
p B.class_variable_defined?(:@@attr) 
p Object.class_variable_defined?(:@@attr)

p A.class_variable_get(:@@attr)
p B.class_variable_get(:@@attr)
p Object.class_variable_get(:@@attr)

p A.class_variables
p B.class_variables
Object.remove_class_variable(:@@attr)
p A.class_variables
p B.class_variables
```

*Output:*

```
true
true
true
222
222
222
[:@@attr]
[:@@attr]
[]
[]
```

***Explanation:*** As per your code `@@attr` belongs to `Object` class class variables. And as per `Ruby` A and B both are subclass of `Object`. Thus the class variables `@@attr` has been shared.

[`Module#class_eval`](http://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/Module#class_eval-instance_method) says:

> > **(a) This can be used to add methods to a class.**
> >
> > **(b) when a block is given, constant/class variable look-up is not affected.**

This is the feature of ruby that if you use `class variable` inside `class_eval` it searches that `class variable` in the class `Object`.

To make it visible I write the below code, which in turn will prove that: ***constant/class variable look-up is not affected.***

```
@@avar = 1
class A < BasicObject
@@avar = "hello"
end
A.class_eval { puts @@avar }
```

Look at the code output:

```
D:/Rubyscript/My ruby learning days/Scripts/TEST.RB:91: warning: class variable
access from toplevel
D:/Rubyscript/My ruby learning days/Scripts/TEST.RB:95: warning: class variable
access from toplevel
1
```

Comment: But class_eval is supposed to add it in the scope of A / B class right.

Comment: @user2231847 see my updated answer and comment please if any doubt.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code,

```
class A
end

class B
end

ADD_ATTR = lambda do
    @@attr = 100
    def self.get_attr
      puts "self : #{self} getting attr : #{@@attr}"
        @@attr
    end
    def self.set_attr(_x)
      puts "self : #{self} setting attr : #{@@attr} to _x : #{_x}"
        @@attr = _x
    end
end

A.class_eval &ADD_ATTR
B.class_eval &ADD_ATTR

a = A.new
b = B.new

A.set_attr(103)
B.set_attr(222)
puts A.get_attr
puts B.get_attr


ADD_BTTR = '
    @@bttr = 100
    def self.get_bttr
      puts "self : #{self} getting bttr : #{@@bttr}"
        @@bttr
    end
    def self.set_bttr(_x)
      puts "self : #{self} setting bttr : #{@@bttr} to _x : #{_x}"
        @@bttr = _x
    end
'
A.class_eval ADD_BTTR
B.class_eval ADD_BTTR

A.set_bttr(103)
B.set_bttr(222)
puts A.get_bttr
puts B.get_bttr
```

It seems that ruby does the block evaluation in the context of object method before joining it to the class, hence the evaluation happens before the code gets attached to the class, it needs to attach the attribute to object method, to prove the point i used the code with the lambda operator.

In the mean while the same code works if we do the class eval with a string

## This is the output I got:

```
self : A setting attr : 100 to _x : 103
self : B setting attr : 103 to _x : 222
self : A getting attr : 222
222
self : B getting attr : 222
222
self : A setting bttr : 100 to _x : 103
self : B setting bttr : 100 to _x : 222
self : A getting bttr : 103
103
self : B getting bttr : 222
222
```